# VisualStudio 2013 weird compile issues

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, build, intellisense

## Issue

I'm having some really odd compile issues using Visual Studio 2013 and it's really disrupting my teams workflow.

The issue is hard to explain but I will provide screen shots and code snippets to help people understand the problems we are facing.

We have a project that we recently moved to VisualStudio 2013 from 2010 and upgraded it to .Net 4.5, the project is a ASP.net Web Forms project.

The code compiles and runs but oddly when I change any of the class files sometimes even just adding a comment `'Test Comment` it fails to compile.

The errors shown in the error window are all wierd and the IntelliSense shows errors in the wrong place, some of the errors are even completly off. An example is `_To is not defined` in the line `Dim _Town as String` or in the same line `'ring' is not defined` which is oviously part of the word String

## ScreenShots

[image: Here are some of the errors after I added the failing code at line 44 and then commented it out and re-compiled]

Here are some of the errors after I added the failing code at line 44 and then commented it out and re-compiled
[image]

## What I've tried

I've tried to change the files line endings and make sure they are all Windows CR+LF, I've tried snooping in the build output nothing I can really see to help me.
I even brung the solution down from source control on another machine to test and it had the same issue. It didn't actually compile properly at all on the new machine but I don't know yet if these two issues are related.

Comment: change things like `Private Property _TelHome As String` to `Private _TelHome As String` - the private ones are members, and not properties

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the code compiles first time and most of the classes have been untouched for years. The issues seems to have started since the jump to 2013 or .Net 4.5. Also to add the properties we would have just been using `prop TAB TAB` to auto generate it. Could this be the actual issue and it was changed in VS2013/.Net4.5 ?

Comment: Look through your list of errors and look for one that isn't in that class. it's quite possible that the error is actually in a different library/project/code and that's not compiling, leaving everything else to fail too. Little difficult to explain. i have a solution with a bunch of projects. If one of them fails then i get errors about that plus errors about a bunch of other compilations that are awaiting the erroneous project to compile.

Comment: Just scrolled through them and they are all related to the project. But are all this wierd issue. Like Syntax not right and points to a point in the file with no text there.
If I reboot my enviroment the project starts compiling again, untill a few changes are made

Comment: Sounds very odd. Have you tried doing a clean before building? (or just use rebuild) other than that, i'm outta ideas :/

Comment: Yup, Tried clean, clean > Rebuild. Only seems to compile after rebooting here's another screenshot just for the giggles ![image](http://i.imgur.com/ihbwHr1.png)

Comment: Try closing the project. Then with File Explorer, delete the "bin" and "obj" folders in the project. Reopen in VS and do a build.

Comment: @TnTinMn Same issue, thank you for your input.

Comment: Have you tired to open the file in another editor like Notepad++? It can show all symbols like cr+lf. Maybe the file was saved as UTF8 with BOM!?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as yours, and also the same scenario (I had upgraded a  very old VB.NET project to a 2013 project).

The issue seem to be related to file encoding. I don't know the exact cause, but it might be having multiple files with different encoding (In my case, some files were ANSI, other files were UTF-8 w/ BOM).

If you aren't sure about having files with different encoding, open them in Notepad++. You should see the file encoding in the bottom-right corner.

At first, I have convert the offending file to ANSI to see if this will resolve the problem. I opened the offending file in Notepad++, selected Encoding-Convert to ANSI, Saved, Encoding->Encode In UTF-8 without BOM, Saved and Reloaded the file in VS. Now the project compile successfully.

However, I didn't want to do this every time I changed the file, (since VS convert it back to UTF8), therefore I copied all the old files (In my case they were 4 files only) to a temporary directory, deleted the files from VS and created new files with the same name, and I copy/pasted the content into each file. Now all my files are in UTF8, and I am no longer having this issue.

**The solution is to either convert your files to ANSI as UTF8, or convert them to UTF8 (This seems to be the default encoding for newly created files in Visual Studio, so I suggest converting them to UTF8)**

If you have a lot of files I think you can try to convert them to UTF8 using Notepad++.

Regards.